# csv live feed from drop shipping website to my website using paypal

Tags: csv, paypal

I'm in the middle of creating my e-commerce website, the coding html css isn't the problem. What I need to do is use a streaming live feed csv from one website and connect it to the products I'm selling on my site, I have absolutely no idea how to do this or even how to start. So I have say a hammer for sale that I have linked to paypal, the drop ship website at the time saids it has 3, but how do I link the details using this csv file to my stock levels in pay pal... I tried researching but I just can't get a grip with it.

Also I just want to add that I'm using godaddy.co.uk for my web hosting, if that helps.

Comment: Not being mean - this is too broad for SO - because you're actually looking for integration work / build a store. And while Paypal is part of the ecommerce flow, the work entailed really has little to do with Paypal itself. You'll need to work with a developer to scope and implement....

Comment: ok cheers EdSF, I had a feeling this was abit out of my depth for now, however they do have an always in stock selection so i'm cool with that.

Comment: Everyone is out of depth on something, that's how/why we learn :) Btw, you can also consider using services that have all of this worked out for you, or at least most of it (even the Paypal end). Not free, but something to consider - re: "build vs buy". Cheers ~